# What is the minimum size of dataset that get high accuracy on machine learning?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, dataset

i'm trying to make an app that get an image of flower and identify it.

I thought to use machine learning, but when I looked up for datasets I found only datasets that contain at most 700 images each flower. 
I understood that it is not enough to get good results.

Does someone know a bigger dataset? And what is the minimum size of dataset that get high accuracy on machine learning?

Do you thing that it is better to that app in image processing instead of ML?

Comment: At least 345341 images. And your final question is especially interesting. I would say "I thing so".

Answer (score -1):

First of all, on what basis are you telling that 700 images of each flower will not give good enough results? I feel that it is good enough for a decent model.

There is no way you can say what the minimum size of data set is. The only way you can know whether you have enough data, is to break the training data into 70%-30%(depends) training data and test data, and then train a model and compare accuracy of the model on training data and test data. If this is satisfactory(depends on application), that means you have enough data for that application. Following is a link of an implementation of a CNN and MLP for the same problem that you want to solve. Hope this helps.

https://www.kaggle.com/olgabelitskaya/the-dataset-of-flower-images